# Wordpress: Output Custom Post Data

Tags: wordpress, output, custom-post-type

I am new to WordPress. In short, I wish to output custom posts onto a page, but several different attempts have been unsuccessful.

I have successfully created a custom post type which saves custom data through custom fields.

```
<?php

    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ->  CREATE SECTION FOR LOCATION MANAGEMENT IN WORDPRESS ADMIN AREA
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    add_action('init', 'location_manager_register');
    function location_manager_register() {
        $args = array(
            'label' => __('Locations'),
            'singular_label' => __('location'),
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail'),
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'locations', 'with_front'=> false)
        );
        register_post_type('locations', $args);

    }

    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ->  ADD BOX WHICH WILL CONTAIN CUSTOM TEXT FIELDS TO NEW SECTION
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    // CREATE THE BOX
    add_action("admin_init", "contact_manager_add_meta");
    function contact_manager_add_meta() {
        add_meta_box(
            "location-meta",
            "Location Options",
            "location_manager_meta_options",
            "locations",    // THIS PLACES THE BOX IN THE RIGHT SECTION
            "normal",       // PLACEMENT WITHIN SECTION
            "high"          // PRIORITY OF BOX
        );
    }

    // CREATE CUSTOM VALUES & ADD TEXT BOXES WITH CUSTOM VALUES
    function location_manager_meta_options() {
        global $post;
        if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
            return $post_id;
        }
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $address = $custom["address"][0];
        $telephone = $custom["telephone"][0];
        $fax = $custom["fax"][0];
        $email = $custom["email"][0];
?>
        <style type="text/css">
            <?php include('css/contact_manager.css'); ?>
        </style>

        <div class="contact_manager_extras">
            <div>
                <label> Address: </label>
                <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $address; ?>"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label> Telephone: </label>
                <input type="text" name="telephone" value="<?php echo $telephone; ?>"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label> Fax: </label>
                <input type="text" name="fax" value="<?php echo $fax; ?>"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label> Email: </label>
                <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
    } // END function location_manager_meta_options

    // ADD FUNCTIONALITY TO SAVE THE FIELD VALUES
    add_action("save_post", "contact_manager_save_extras");
    function contact_manager_save_extras() {
        global $post;
        if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
            return $post_id;
        }
        else {
            update_post_meta($post->ID, "store_name", $_POST["store_name"]);
            update_post_meta($post->ID, "address", $_POST["address"]);
            update_post_meta($post->ID, "telephone", $_POST["telephone"]);
            update_post_meta($post->ID, "fax", $_POST["fax"]);
            update_post_meta($post->ID, "email", $_POST["email"]);
        }
    }

?>
```

This shows the interface in the Wordpress admin area:
http://eoghanoloughlin.com/link_images/custom_fields.jpg

Finally, this is where the problem is, I want to output the information onto a page. Here is the code I am currently using:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Locations */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php query_posts('post_type=locations'); ?>

<section class="middle">
    <div class="container location">

        <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
            <!-- MAIN AREA -->
        <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

        <div class="main">
            <img src="<?php echo IMAGES ?>/content/dublin_map.jpg" class="location_map">


            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php 
                global $post;
                $address = get_post_custom_values('address')[0];
                $telephone = get_post_custom_values('telephone')[0];
                $fax = get_post_custom_values('fax')[0];
                $email = get_post_custom_values('email')[0];
            ?>

            <article>

                <h6> <?php the_title(); ?> </h6>

                <address> <p> <span>Address:</span> <?php echo $address; ?> </p> </address>

                <p> <span>Tel:</span> <a href="tel:+045-444365" >045-444365</a> </p>

                <p> <span>Fax:</span> <?php echo $fax; ?> </p>

                <p> <span>Email:</span> <a href="mailto:<?php echo $email; ?>"><?php echo $email; ?></a> </p>

            </article>

            <?php
                endwhile;
                endif;
            ?>

        </div>

        <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
            <!-- SIDE BAR -->
        <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

        <aside>
            <?php get_sidebar('main'); ?>
        </aside>

    </div>
</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The key parts in this last piece of code being the "query_posts()" function and then the loop.

As I said, I am new to wordpress, I cannot figure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'locations',
    'some_thing_here' => '',
    'some_thing_here' => '',
    'some_thing_here' => '',
    'some_thing_here' => ''
);

$mylocations = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $mylocations -> have_posts() ) : while ( $mylocations->have_posts() ) : $mylocations -> the_post();

?>

<?php the_title(); ?>    
<?php the_content(); ?>    

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

    Oops, there are no Locations.

<?php endif; ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

**EDIT**

And there is an [Smashing Magazine Article](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/14/using-wp_query-wordpress/) on the subject with some additional examples.

Remember my php is pretty basic, but I think you can put the meta date in a $ by doing the following.

```
<?php 
    $adress = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'adres', true);
    $telephone = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'telephone', true);
    $fax = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fax', true);
?>
```

And than echo it out:

```
<?php echo $adress; ?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: might want to check out http://www.advancedcustomfields.com realy powerfull with meta boxes and such.

Comment: Thank You, but how would I specifically target the custom fields, like address & email etc? Like underneath the_content() ?